# PMT Formula with negative interest

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to calculate monthly "payment". My PV is 1000, FV is 2000 and interest is negative 4% and N = 12

X = PMT (-0.04,12,1000,2000,0) = -269.85

However - If I use a manual schedule, PMT is 143.28

Am I using the PMT formula wrong ?

The question I'm trying to answer with a formula is:
How big does a monthly contribution needs to be given that principal shrinks by 4% every month, starting amount is 1000 and the goal is to reach 2000 in 12 time periods.

Add is a constant amount and independent of PV. It is the unknown I'm trying to calculate given PV, FV, R and N. Drop is a function of open amount and R.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77113774/edit) instead of adding info in comments

Comment: Yes you are using the pmt function wrong. You only use future value if you have a ballon payment due at the end of the loan. You also never input the interest rate as negative number. You also must make sure the interest rate is adjusted for one period, so if you APR is 4%, then your monthly period rate would be 4%/12.

Comment: 4% is indeed monthly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the PV value as a negative number

```
 = PMT (-0.04,12,-1000,2000,0)
```

Comment: Thank you - This worked - but now I'm curious why and how ?

Comment: This belongs to bookkeeping standards.

Answer (score 0):

Bing came through with the answer

x = (goal - starting amount * (1 - shrinkage) ^ time periods) / (((1 - shrinkage) ^ time periods - 1) / shrinkage)